# Can I set styles to document body from styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I want to know if there is a possibility to cast styles from `styled-components` to wrapping element, like `<body>` tag in the way that looks like this:

```
class SomePageWrapper = styled.div`
  body {
    font-size: 62.5%
  }
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out - you can't set styled components to outer elements. This violates the philosophy of encapsulation - a benefit from `styled-components`.

So the way to do this would be to add a new class to `body` element called `classList` via JS in the parent component with `componentDidMount()` and remove it with `componentWillUnmount()`.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can use the global inject function to set stuff on your body like this:

```
import { injectGlobal } from 'styled-components';

injectGlobal`
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Operator Mono';
    src: url('../fonts/Operator-Mono.ttf');
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
`;
```

The example is from here: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#injectglobal

Comment: The injectGlobal API was removed and replaced by [createGlobalStyle](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle) in styled-components v4.

Answer (score 2):

**For v4** styled-components, use createGlobalStyle .

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    color: ${props => (props.whiteColor ? 'white' : 'black')};
  }
`

// later in your app

<React.Fragment>
  <GlobalStyle whiteColor />
  <Navigation /> {/* example of other top-level stuff */}
</React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't do that.

```
class SomePageWrapper = styled.body`
  font-size: 62.5%
`
```

So,when you put `<SomePageWrapper/>` in the render,it turns to be `<body></body>`.Then you need to put it in the root part,to replace `<body>`.

But how do you replace the `<body>` you have in `index.html`.When you can't replace it,you will end up two `<body>` in browser,or something weird will happen.

Just simply use css file for